# SQL - auto find off_set number with two columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm sure there is a better method that I can't think of right now.  If you look at the Current data screenshot, I'm trying to find the final start_time and finish_time like in the second screenshot.  I have been playing around with the LEAD function, but the offset is not always the same and I really don't want to hardcode it. I'm trying to find the offset by using Start_flag column as the start of the count or sum when there is a 1 and end the count or sum when it finds the 1 in the Finish_Flag column. I tried to do the **sum() over partition by** and **count() over partition by** but not sure how to apply two columns to those.  The database I'm reading from is Oracle 12.2.

[image: Current Data]

[image: Results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `analytical functions` and `group by` as follows:

```
select part, 
       min(start_time) as start_time, 
       max(start_flag) as start_flag, 
       max(finish_flag) as finish_flag
       max(case when finish_flag = 1 then finish_time end) as finish_time
from
       (select t.*, 
               sum(start_flag) over (partition by part order by start_time) as sm
          from your_table t) 
group by part, sm
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the next finish for each start using a cumulative minimum max.  Then filter to just have the starts:

```
select part, start_time, start_flag, finish_flag, finish_time
from (select t.*,
             min(case when finish_flag = 1 then finish_time end) over (partition by part order by start_time) as finish_time
      from t
     ) t
where start_flag = 1;
```

`lead()` doesn't work because the finish time might be in the same row.